# How to change locale to English?

Tags: locale

I have message from bash and it's localized, I want English message, my locale is:

```
$ locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pl:en
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I've try:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8; type grunt
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; type grunt
LC_MESSAGES=en_EN.UTF-8 && type grunt
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8; type grunt
```

But the message keep showing up in Polish:

```
ścieżka do grunt jest zapamiętana (/usr/local/bin/grunt)
```

How can I make this text English?

**EDIT**

I've run:

```
$ eval $(locale | sed -e 's/\(.*\)=.*/export \1=en_US.UTF-8/')             
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and type grunt show polish message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your semicolon/`&&`. The way you're doing it, the shell is executing your assignment as a separate command. Thus, `type` is never seeing it. Do it this way instead:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 type grunt
```

This tells your shell to temporarily set the environment variable `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, execute `type`, then reset `LC_ALL` to whatever it was before.

Comment: It's strange, I think someting is wrong with `type` command because it's keep showing me translated message.

Comment: @jcubic it may be due to the fact that `type` is a built-in. I'm not sure.

Comment: Also `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 xxx` give localized file not found message. But when I run `eval $(locale | sed -e 's/\(.*\)=.*/export \1=en_US.UTF-8/')` it give me english one, maybe you need to use different variable for that too, I've tried `LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 xxx` and it also give Polish not found message.

Comment: @jcubic try `LC_ALL=C` or `LANG=C`

Comment: `LANG x` return localized message but `LANG=C bash -c "x"` give english one. `LC_ALL=C bash -c "x"` also work.

Comment: @jcubic `LANG x` or `LANG=C x`?

Comment: I've try `LANG=C x`